# How to use Vue.js variable/parameter inside v-if condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to pass a dynamic variable into `v-if` attribute.
I tried multiple ways but it doesn't produce the expected result.

So far, I have this: `v-if="customDropdown === {{row.name}}"`

How can I conditionally and dynamically render the element, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use interpolation... `v-if="customDropdown == row.name"`

Comment: @DawidZbiński , It helped! Thanks :)

Comment: Added it as an answer, would appreciate marking it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use interpolation in Vue directives/attributes.

To bind to `v-if` or `v-for` use variables directly:

```
<div v-if="value.someProperty"></div>
```

To bind to other attributes/properties use `v-bind:` or shorthand `:` as follows:

```
<div :directive="value"></div>
```

Template Syntax [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need binding the `row.name` to data object in vue:

`export default {
    data() {
        return {
            customDropdown: 'something',
            row: {name: 'something'},
        }
    }
}`

and then use it in the `v-if` statement:

```
<div v-if="customDropdown == row.name">You see me if customDropdown is equal to row.name</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot interpolate directives/attributes and second, it's not clear, but I think you want to check the condition while iterating by a array.

You can use the template structure below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div
    v-for="row in arrayList"
    v-if="customDropdown === row.name"
    >
    Show row content: {{ row }}
  </div>
</div>
```

With the data structure below to achieve you goal:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    customDropdown: 'first',
    arrayList: [
      {
        name: 'first',
      },
      {
        name: 'second',
      },
     ],
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the properties name,

For example

```
export default {
 data() {
    return {
       var: true 
     }
  }
}
```

html

```
<span v-if="var">I only appear when the condition is true</span>
```